# How to avoid label overlapping in Groupcheckbox in Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

So I created an App in Shiny which is running and I also uploaded it on shinyapps.io. When I was creating the App i was working with my computer at home which has a screen size of 24inches. Now a friend of mine who was checking out my app told me that on his Screen the labels are overlapping (which was not the case on my screen). So my question now is how can i make the content inside certain boxes resize automatically depending on the screen size of the user.

I tryed resizing the boxes but this doesnt change the content inside. Im sure there is a CSS solution but I was not able to find one yet.

So here is one example of one of my tabs (I did all the taps in the global.R enviroment seperately and then jsut added them all in my ui.R)

So this is one of my tabs. and the checkbox labels overlap if the screensize is to small.

```
# tab6 --> africa
tab6 = tabItem(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .multicol {
                    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
                    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
                    column-count: 3;
                    }
                    "))

    ),
  tabName = "africa",
  box(height = 770,width = 6, plotOutput("graph6", hover = "plot_hover6", height = 650),verbatimTextOutput("info6")), # box1 closing
  box(title = "Settings",  height = 770, width = 6,
      wellPanel(
        sliderInput(inputId = "range6",
                    label = "Choose the year range:",
                    min = 2002, max = 2020, value = c(2002,2020)),
        selectInput(inputId = "dis6",
                    label = "Choose the district",
                    choices = unique(Africa$District)),
        tags$div(class = "multicol", prettyCheckboxGroup(inputId = "con6",
                                                         label = "Choose the place of birth",choices = unique(Africa$Country),selected = unique(Africa$Country)[27],outline = T, plain = T, icon = icon("check-circle")))))#box2 closing
    )# tabitem closing
```

This is my ui where I simply added all the tabs which i did in my global enviroment.

```
# head of the dashboard
header = dashboardHeader(title = "Vienna")

# sidebar
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(text = "Read Me", tabName = "readme", icon = icon("readme")),
    menuItem(text = "Migration", tabName = "migration", icon = icon("globe-americas"),menuSubItem(text = "EU before 2004", tabName = "eu1", icon = icon("bar-chart")),menuSubItem(text = "EU after 2004", tabName = "eu2", icon = icon("bar-chart")), menuSubItem(text = "Non-EU Countries", tabName = "noneu", icon = icon("bar-chart")),menuSubItem(text = "America", tabName = "america", icon = icon("bar-chart")),menuSubItem(text = "Asia", tabName = "asia", icon = icon("bar-chart")), menuSubItem(text = "Africa", tabName = "africa", icon = icon("bar-chart")),  menuSubItem(text = "Oceania", tabName = "oceania", icon = icon("bar-chart"))),# first menu item 
    menuItem(text = "Real Estate Prices", icon = icon("sign"), tabName = "realestate", menuSubItem(text = "Appartments", tabName = "app", icon = icon("building")),  menuSubItem(text = "Houses", tabName = "house", icon = icon("home")), menuSubItem(text = "Land", tabName = "land", icon = icon("layer-group"))
    )# second menu item
  ) # sidebar menu
)# dashboard sidebar

#C0C0C0
# body 
body = dashboardBody(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                            /* body */
                            .content-wrapper, .right-side {
                            background-color: #96A2A4;
                            }

                            '))),

  tabItems(
    # ReadMe
    tab0,
    # Denography
    tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5, tab6, tab7,
    # Property Prices
    tab8, tab9, tab10
  ) # tabITEMS   
  )# fluid page
)

# dashboardbody



# full UI compressed
ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "blue")
```

So what I am trying to do is to create a box() which will resize the content inside (f.i. CheckBox labels) depending on the size of the screen.